# In what cases and with what method does one find a time dependent probability density for a quantum system in an infinite square well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, probability

How can one find the time dependent probability density function of a quantum system given $\Psi(x,t=0)$? Say, $\psi(x) \sim x^4$ for $0 < x < L$. How can one find the time dependant probability density knowing $\psi(x)$?

Knowing that the most general solution to the time dependent Schrodinger equation is:

$\Psi(x,t) = \sum_{n} a_n \psi(x)_n e^{-i E_n t / \hbar}$

and knowing that $\psi(x)$ has no dependence on $n$, then when one tries to take $P(x,t) = |\Psi(x,t)|^2$, all the time dependent terms drop out and one is left with a time independent probability density.

Comment: Try taking this as an example: $\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x) \left(a_1 e^{-i E_1 t / \hbar} + a_2 e^{-i E_2 t / \hbar} \right)$. Compute $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$. If you really do it, you'll find a time dependent term (it will be proportional to $\sin((E_1-E_2)t/\hbar)$, or maybe cosine).

Comment: As a separate point, I don't understand why you say $\psi(x)_n$ has no dependence on $n$. The $\psi(x)_n$ in your expansion should satisfy the time independent Schrodinger equation $\hat{H} \psi_n = E_n \psi_n$, so the $\psi_n$ will depend on $n$. What you should really do is solve for the $a_n$ such that $\Psi(x,0) \sim$ (initial wavefunction). But, this is not directly relevant to your main question.

Comment: @Andrew I say that $\psi(x)$ has no dependence on $n$ because the function was given as part of the problem, and the first part of the question asked for a factor of $A$ such that $\psi(x)$ is normalized. All this required was a simple computation of $\int_0^L |\psi(x)|^2 dx = 1$. This factor of $A$ has no dependence on $n$ since it is just a constant, and since $\psi(x)$ contains no $sin$ or $cos$ terms, $\psi(x)$ has no $n$ dependency.


I will try to compute the solution you offered above right now though, thank you.

Comment: I agree $\Psi(x,0)=\psi(x)$ has no dependence on $n$. My problem is more when you write $\Psi = \sum_n a_n \psi_n e^{-i E_n t/\hbar}$, the $\psi_n$ which appear in _that_ expression are different from $\Psi(x,0)$ and they _do_ depend on $n$.

Comment: @Andrew Can you explain to me how that can be? Is it simply multiplying $\psi(x)$ by a factor of $n$?

Comment: The $\psi_n$ are eigenfunctions of $\hat{H} \psi_n = E_n \psi_n$. Only for eigenfunctions does $\Psi = \sum_n a_n \psi_n e^{-i E_n t/\hbar}$ apply. Any linear combination of eigenfunctions is also a solution to the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: @dumpythepickler Try for example hyperphysics: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/pbox.html. That gives you the $\psi_n$ for the infinite square well.

Comment: @Andrew going back to my original issue, I have tried doing as your suggested, computing $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ using $\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x) \left(a_1 e^{-i E_1 t / \hbar} + a_2 e^{-i E_2 t / \hbar} \right)$ and $\Psi\star(x,t)=\psi(x) \left(a_1 e^{+i E_1 t / \hbar} + a_2 e^{+i E_2 t / \hbar} \right)$ and I don't seem to arrive at a meaningful result unless I'm doing something wrong. Taking $\omega_1 , \omega_2 = E_1 / \hbar , E_2 / \hbar$ respectively, I arrive at $|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = a_1 a_2 \left(e^{i(\omega_2 - \omega_1)t} + e^{i(\omega_1 - \omega_2)t} \right)$ which doesn't seem to have any significance

Comment: The significance is that this is an explicit example where $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ is time dependent, whereas your main confusion in the question was that you couldn't see how $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ could ever be time dependent. In fact the answer you quote can be rewritten $2 a_1 a_2 \cos((\omega_1-\omega_2)t)$. As an aside (not the main point), you also should have found $a_1^2 + a_2^2$ as well (assuming $a_1$ and $a_2$ are real).

Comment: @Andrew I'm aware that in general $\psi(x)_n$ is given by $\psi(x)_n = \sqrt(2/L) \sin(n \pi x / L)$, however, I am given a specific $\psi(x)$ to begin with. It was my understanding that I should not use the sine function because I was given $\psi(x)$?

Comment: I am leaving an answer to give some more explanation, see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two different concepts that you are mixing up (perhaps partly because you use the same letter $\psi$ to refer to both concepts).

1. There is the initial wave function, which I'll call $f$, so $\Psi(x,0)=f(x)$.
2. Then there are the energy eigenfunctions, $u_n(x)$. It is true that 
   \begin{equation}
   \Psi(x,t)=\sum_n a_n u_n(x) e^{-i \omega_n t}
   \end{equation}
   where I am using $\omega_n = E_n / \hbar$.

Now to relate these, we have
\begin{equation}
\Psi(x,0) = f(x) = \sum_n a_n u_n(x)
\end{equation}
We can solve for the $a_n$ by using the orthonormality of the $u_n$.

Then after we have solved for the $a_n$, the time dependence of $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ is fixed (just plug those numerical values of $a_n$ into the general formula for $\Psi(x,t)$). The key thing is that $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ will be time dependent if there is more than one nonzero $a_n$. To see that is true, you can just compute $|\Psi(x,t)|^2$ for an explicit example such as $\Psi(x,t) = a_1 u_1(x) e^{-i \omega_1 t} + a_2 u_2(x) e^{-i \omega_2 t}$.

---

To respond to some comments:

To compute $\Psi(x,t)$ you need to know both the $a_n$ and the $u_n(x)$.

The way you compute the $u_n(x)$ is by solving the time independent Schrodinger equation $\hat{H} u_n = E_n u_n$. So the $u_n$ will depend on the potential you choose. For the infinite square well potential the $u_n$ are given by $\sin(n\pi x / L)$ (up to normalization).

The way you compute $a_n$ is by using orthormality, $a_n = \int dx u_n^\star(x) f(x)$.

If you want more detail you can find worked examples in any undergrad level quantum mechanics text, such as Griffifths.

Answer (score 0):

$\Psi(x,t) = \sum_{n} a_n \psi(x)_n e^{-i E_n t / \hbar}$

Yes, if $\psi(x)_n$ and $E_n$ are the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues.  When you take the absolute square, you must keep all the terms:

$$|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = \sum_{k}\sum_{n} a_k^*a_n \psi^*_k(x)\psi_n(x) e^{-i (E_n-E_j) t / \hbar}$$

The probability density is $|\Psi(x,t)|^2 \textrm{d}x$, and it is time dependent.  If you integrate this over the whole square well, then the double sum will collapse because 
$$ \int_{well}\textrm{d}x\ \psi_k^*(x)\psi_n(x) = \delta_{kn}.$$

That leaves $|\Psi(x,t)|^2 = \sum\limits_{n} a_n^*a_n=1$, which is time independent.

On the other hand, if you calculate $<x>$, the integral
$$ \int_{well}\textrm{d}x\ \psi_k^*(x)\,x\,\psi_n(x) $$ is not zero in general which means you will be left with time-dependent terms in $<x>$.

You find the coefficients $a_n$ by doing the integral
$$a_n = \int_{well}\textrm{d}x\ \Psi^*(x,0)\psi_n(x).$$

Comment: This seems to along the same lines as what @Andrew was saying. I am following Griffiths' example 2.2, however, I am finding that $a_n = \int_{well}\textrm{d}x\ \Psi^*(x,0)\psi_n(x)$ is extremely difficult to calculate because it involves calculating the following integrals: $\int_{0}^{L} x^2 \sin(n \pi x / L) dx$ and $\int_{0}^{L} x^4 \sin(n \pi x / L) dx$. Is there some mathematical method I am missing, because these don't seem to yield a concise statement for $a_n$ like Griffiths example does.

Comment: @dumpythepickler Those integrals are actually doable using a few tricks that are very useful to learn. Write the first one as ${\rm Im} \int x^2 e^{i \pi x / L} dx$ ( where Im = imaginary part). Then introduce a parameter $\lambda$ that we will set to 1 at the end. The trick is that we can write the integral as $(L/i\pi)^2(d^2/d\lambda^2)\left({\rm Im} \int e^{i \pi x \lambda / L}\right)$. Now do the integral first, then take the two derivatives wrt $\lambda$, and finally set $\lambda=1$, and you'll have your answer.

Comment: I look those up in a table of integrals.  You can calculate them using integration by parts, too.